# When I using hive in flutter , ios simulator can not run,

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, emulation

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           18,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/lw/s0wrzngj5vz7fzqd1349cb1c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.vdi8q9/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirVK4qWh/temporary_xcresult_bundle
: Error: The getter 'box' isn't defined for the class 'WatchBoxBuilder Function()'.
../…/src/watch_box_builder.dart:54

- 'WatchBoxBuilder' is from 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive_flutter-1.1.0/lib/hive_flutter.dart').
  package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'box'.
  if (widget.box != oldWidget.box) {
  ^^^
  : Error: The getter 'box' isn't defined for the class 'WatchBoxBuilder Function()'.
  ../…/src/watch_box_builder.dart:61
- 'WatchBoxBuilder' is from 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive_flutter-1.1.0/lib/hive_flutter.dart').
  package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'box'.
  subscription = widget.box.watch().listen((event) {
  ^^^
  : Error: The getter 'watchKeys' isn't defined for the class 'WatchBoxBuilder Function()'.
  ../…/src/watch_box_builder.dart:62
- 'WatchBoxBuilder' is from 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive_flutter-1.1.0/lib/hive_flutter.dart').
  package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'watchKeys'.
  if (widget.watchKeys != null && !widget.watchKeys!.contains(event.key)) {
  ^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The getter 'watchKeys' isn't defined for the class 'WatchBoxBuilder Function()'.
  ../…/src/watch_box_builder.dart:62
- 'WatchBoxBuilder' is from 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive_flutter-1.1.0/lib/hive_flutter.dart').
  package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'watchKeys'.
  if (widget.watchKeys != null && !widget.watchKeys!.contains(event.key)) {
  ^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The method 'builder' isn't defined for the class 'WatchBoxBuilder Function()'.
  ../…/src/watch_box_builder.dart:76
- 'WatchBoxBuilder' is from 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive_flutter-1.1.0/lib/hive_flutter.dart').
  package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'builder'.
  return widget.builder(context, widget.box);
  ^^^^^^^
  : Error: The getter 'box' isn't defined for the class 'WatchBoxBuilder Function()'.
  ../…/src/watch_box_builder.dart:76
- 'WatchBoxBuilder' is from 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive_flutter-1.1.0/lib/hive_flutter.dart').
  package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'box'.
  return widget.builder(context, widget.box);
  ^^^
  : Error: Expected an identifier, but got ')'.
  lib/myHive.dart:21
  Try inserting an identifier before ')'.
  );
  ^
  : Error: Expected ';' after this.
  lib/myHive.dart:20
  );
  ^
  : Error: Unexpected token ';'.
  lib/myHive.dart:21
  );
  ^
  Failed to package /Users/ekrembulut/Desktop/FlutterProjects/hiveee.
  Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
  note: Using new build system
  note: Planning
  note: Build preparation complete
  note: Building targets in dependency order
  Result bundle written to path:
  /var/folders/lw/s0wrzngj5vz7fzqd1349cb1c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.vdi8q9/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirVK4qWh/temporary_xcresult_bundle
  Could not build the application for the simulator.
  Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.

Comment: Please provide more info about your problem. Here is [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sir . I solved problem . I will explain how to solve . Hive library is using its methods as a static but it should use with constructor. When error was triggering , we should use “()” for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem . I will explain how to solve . Hive library is using its methods as a static but it should use with constructor. When error was triggering , we should use “()” for solution . In package , change widget.something to widget().something.